# Determine if email is from free email provider or ISP

Tags: c#, email

Is there a way in C# to determine if a email address is from an isp or free email service?

I want to determine if the email is corporate or personal,  similar to how yammer does it on their sign up form.

Comment: Some ISPs provide free email services. Most email services, free or not, are corporate in nature. I'm afraid your problem will not be easy to solve.

Comment: And what if our corporation uses gmail? There's no distinction between "personal" and "corporate" email addresses. Also, there are more email servers than just "web based" and "ISP". What about the use of something like Microsoft Exchange? That's not from an ISP. Unless it's hosted in the cloud somewhere, in which case it could be from an ISP, or it could be from a hosting company, or it could be my company's email server.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing C# can tell you about if an email address if a personal or business email address or the distinction. Infact, no language can tell you that! 
This requires some coding on your part and whether or not it is possible. But don't think it is really possible because, as @John Saunders has said, what if people are using gmail for business? But also their employees could have their own gmail address for personal usage... so how would you find the distinction?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is by having a list of all non-corporate addresses and comparing your address extension to that list. If it's not found, it's not from a free email service.

However, a number of companies use personal style addresses. And it's not that hard to set up your own mail server with your own domain name. Hell, I had to setup a mail server for one of my classes in college, and domain names are cheap on sites like GoDaddy. If I wanted to, I could probably setup a mail server over the weekend.